# Mongoose/MongoDB find nested/embedded array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nested, find

I am trying to use find() to search data based on _id and value of field1, return the whole nested_object. I have look up the documentation and also other answer in Stackoverflow, stuck on this for few days, please let me know how I can get this to work? thank you.

```
_id: someID
array: [
   {nested_object1: 
       {field1: a}
       {field2: b}
       {field3: c}
   }
   {nested_object2:
       {field1: d}
       {field2: e}
       {field3: f}
   }
   {nested_object3:
       {field1: g}
       {field2: h}
       {field3: i}
   }
]
```

Comment: data you have provided is neither a valid object nor contains any array. provide a valid object/Json structure of your data.

Comment: @Robot Thanks for spotting it out, I have edited and make the correction, thank you